# Using PlotRange with ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

ListLogLinearPlot does not seem to respond to the PlotRange option. For example, this code:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{1., 5., 3.}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.0, 10.0}, {0.0, 3.0}}, Joined -> True]
```

gives exactly the same plot as this code:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{1., 5., 3.}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.0, 100.0}, {0.0, 10.0}}, Joined -> True]
```

That's not how I interpret the documentation on PlotRange. Mathematica version 11.1.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The cuplrit is the first 0 in the `x` range. A logarithm of 0 is not determined, so the plot can't put a 0 on the axis. Try changing it to anything other than 0:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{1., 5., 3.}, PlotRange -> {{1., 10.0}, {0.0, 10.0}}, Joined -> True]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{1., 5., 3.}, PlotRange -> {{.01, 10.0}, {0.0, 10.0}}, Joined -> True]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but after reading information abour `PlotRange` looks like the `PlotRangePadding` limits `PlotRange`, at least it changed the plot for me:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{1., 5., 3.}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 100.0}, {0.0, 10.0}}, PlotRangePadding -> {3, 2},
  Joined -> True]
```

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate to learn how to enter special words, or a plot ... I try to look for this but do not found